# In PayFlow Pro, is there a way to duplicate or copy an existing billing profile?

Tags: c#, paypal, payflowpro

I am currently working on the billing engine for a website. There is a scenario in the business logic that forces me to determine if a user is currently a member of the site and if so, copy their current billing profile to a new billing profile, credit card and all of the other fields. From this point, get the new billing profile and keep just keep track of both.

I am trying to keep the user from having to re-enter their billing information. I have reviewed the doc. but am unable to see how this could be done without keeping a copy of the credit card information on my system and that is not what we want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a credit card funded billing profile you can use one of the transactions of your current profile in an API call as a reference to create a new profile.

Comment: So I would have to look use the "I (Inquiry)" action to look up the transaction history and copy one of the transactions that are returned?  Also, would I get the entire credit card number returned back to me along with the expiration date?

Comment: Pass in the ORIGID=[a previous transaction (PNREF]) you shouldn't need the credit card numbers again.  Exception might be on those with expired cards.  Check out the example for "Converting an Existing Transaction Into a Profile" https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/recurring-billing/#using-the-add-action

Comment: So I would have to look use the "I (Inquiry)" action to look up the transaction history and copy one of the transactions that are returned?  Also, would I get the entire credit card number returned back to me along with the expiration date?  I am using the PayFlowNetAPI.SubmitTransaction to send the payplay request.  Would I still be able to use this same approach?

Comment: Yes, that should do it

Comment: I think I get it.  1) Get the PNREF of a previous transaction for the current ORIGID.   2) Set the new transaction ORIGID = to the copied PNREF.  3) Get the new ORIGID that is generated.

Comment: I apologize if I am not 100% following. The ORIGID would be equal to the  PNREF you want to COPY the values of.  So if you did use an inquiry to get the history then one of those PNREFs should work as the ORIGID to create a new profile.